# Trigger for job with possible delay

Tags: c#, quartz.net

How to construct quartz trigger that will wait for delayed job?

For example:
Trigger is set to run job every 5 minute but job can take more than 5 minute.

I would like to finish delayed job a than start new interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of scheduling the job to run every 5 minutes, create it as single time job and reschedule it each time it is executed to run again in 5 minutes.